# import.io display data on wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, import.io

I have built an api using import.io to get some data about a product from a url.

I'm new to this and need a bit of help, how to I display the information gathered from a specific url on my wordpress page?

Sorry if I'm not explaining well but as I haven't done this before I don't know how to display the data from the api on my pages.

Basically I want to display a bunch of products from different urls on my wordpress site and I'm using import.io to get the data as it appears to do a good accurate job, I just dond know how to use the 2 together.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am not too familiar with using wordpress to integrate third party API data, but the import.io API documentation can be found here

http://api.docs.import.io/

A very high level approach would be:

- Call the import.io extractor API from wordpress
- Format the data from the API into the format you want on the page
- Display the data on the page